# React call a function after another onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have onClick event, that is a trigger for couple functions. Function`setRcomForApi(rcom)` sets values`ip1, port1` for function `getApiVersion(ip1, port1)`. The problem is - on first click `ip1, port1` are `undefined`. I've tried to use callback - but it didn't work...

```
 const onClick = () => {
        setIndexPpk(index);
        setRcomForApi(rcom);   //sets ip1 and port1 in Context State.    
        getApiVersion(ip1, port1);  // on first click both undefined          
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `Promise` ? Also, are `ip1, port1` both stateful values?

Comment: Simply add a condition to check if needed would be good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because setRcomForApi(rcom) is asynchronous. So you need to use an useEffect to check for changes in values of ip1 and port1

```
 useEffect(() => {
if(ip1 && port1) {
    getApiVersion(ip1, port1);
}
}, [ip1, port1]);
```